# How long does Banutu's dragonstone last?

Tags: fire-emblem-mystery-of-the-emblem

I've been playing Fire Emblem: Mystery of the Emblem and while using Banutu, i noticed after a while he reverts back to a manakete. fighting an enemy seems to extend this but he will still revert after a while. so I don't end up using all of his dragonstone uses, **how long after using Banutu's dragonstone do i have before he reverts to a manakete?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://fireemblemwiki.org, Dragonstones last for 5 turns, with the exception of the Earthstone, which will turn Medeus for the remainder of the chapter.

The different Dragonstones available in Mystery of the Emblem:

- [Firestone](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Firestone)
- [Magestone](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Magestone)
- [Wyvernstone](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Wyvernstone) (Tiki only)
- [Divinestone](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Divinestone) (Tiki only)
- [Earthstone](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Earthstone) (Medeus only)

All of them have 18 uses, adding up to 80 turns of transformation per stone.

Comment: Does attacking reset the counter?

Comment: @BlazingTrio. Sorry, I can't find any information about that, and since I don't own a copy of the game, I can't verify it myself either. If I'm not mistaken, the SNES games don't auto-save like the GBA ones do, so you could run the tests with Bantu upon starting a new chapter, and simply reload the chapter once you're done with the tests.